# How to reset sessionStorage on every link click except one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with using infinite-scroll and returning the user to his previous position. I'm storing the user's scroll position and post content that was loaded via AJAX in the sessionStorage. Problem is that I want to reset this session if he clicks on any button/link except the post-page link. 
So I have this

```
    $("a").on( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".refresh").attr("is-refresh", "false");
        //If user doesn't click on a post link we will reset storage to its default.
        if($(this).hasClass('post-page')) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("scroll_position", $(window).scrollTop());
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        } else {
            sessionStorage.removeItem("posts_to_append");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("pagination_to_append");
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
```

Problem is that this doesn't help if user clicks on the refresh page button. I've been thinking a lot and can't come up with a simple solution.

If it helps here is my gist with the code that does the whole infinite scroll including keeping the user's position. I just need to identify page refresh via the refresh button.
https://gist.github.com/itzikbenh/5cc5fb05b393a1516af70bc0fde3fa18

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh page button"?

Comment: The refresh icon on every browser. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

What you lack are `$(function () {})` and `sessionStorage.removeItem`.

Here, try this.

```
$(function () { 
    // code inside this function will execute on every page refresh afer the DOM is ready

    clearScrollPosition();

    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('post-page') == false) 
            clearScrollPosition();
    });

    function clearScrollPosition() {
        // clear a session storage item
        sessionStorage.removeItem('scroll_position');
    }
});
```